# matlab generalized cross correlation and ROTH Filter

Tags: matlab, filter, cross-correlation

I have a problem for finding cross correlation of tho signals. No filtere version works but ROTH filter version does not work. Can you tell me the problem please ? Thanks

```
tho=2;
A=1;
t=-15:0.1:15;
FFTLength=length(t);

x= rect( t+1,tho,A );  % First rectangle signal

plot(t,x)

hold on

y=rect(t-4,tho,A);  

plot(t,y,'r')

for i=1:length(x)
    x(i)=x(i)+normrnd(0,0.1);
end
figure
plot(t,x,'r') 

for i=1:length(y)
    y(i)=y(i)+normrnd(0,0.1);
end
figure
plot(t,y,'r')

Rxx = xcorr(x);
Ryy = xcorr(y);
Rxy = xcorr(x,y);
Sxx = fft(Rxx,FFTLength);
Syy = fft(Ryy,FFTLength);
Sxy = fft(Rxy,FFTLength);

X=fft(x,301);
Y=fft(y,301);

%Filtering
H=1;
X2=X.*H;
Y2=Y.*H;

x_t=ifft(X2);
y_t=ifft(Y2);

[correlation,lags] = xcorr(y_t,x_t);
delay = lags(find(correlation==max(correlation)))
disp('Plain time ')

X2=fft(x).*(1./Sxx);
Y2=fft(Y).*(1./Sxx);

x2=real(ifft(X2));
y2=real(ifft(Y2));

[correlation2,lags2] = xcorr(x2,y2);
delay2 = lags2(find(correlation2==max(correlation2)))
disp('ROTH Filter ');
```

by the way rect is ;

```
function [ y ] = rect( t,tho,A )

    for i = 1 : length(t)

        if  -(tho / 2) <= t(i) && t(i) <= (tho / 2) 
            y(i) = A * 1;

        else
            y(i) = 0;

        end

    end

end
```

Comment: what is the error?  how do you know it doesn't work?

Comment: The correct delay must be 50 , my plain time is correct , filtered version should also be correct , but it comes 150, 30 , 130 ... , the problem is ROTH Filter part, it does not work correctly.